# CRUD use case and <<extend>>

Tags: use-case

[image: Use case diagram] I made a use case diagram for store management system. I identified a few CRUD use cases as you can see on diagram. Can I extend CRUD use case, like here: Manage transactions from Manage Suppliers, or just leave it as another use case? Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2448448/50447

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41553079/1746685 I like the suggestion by @thomas-kilian to mark the respective use case bubbles with the stereotype `<<CRUD>>`. Short and makes it obvious what is meant by "manage".