# Breaking down CRUD In Use Case Modeling

Tags: uml, use-case

I have a follow up question from [CRUD in a use-case diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772399/crud-in-a-use-case-diagram)

If i  am required to break down complex use case such as "**Manage User**" (Let's assume this is complex), would it be alright to extend them into different cases? Or should i use include?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine. `<<extend>>` means that the extending UC is optional.

As a side note: avoid `<<extend>>` and `<<include>>` since they are a sign of functional decomposition. And that's not what you are supposed to do with use case synthesis. CRUD however is a borderline case. So, this should be fine.

Comment: FWIW: Sometimes I simply use `<<CRUD>>` as stereotype, which saves the 4 extending bubbles.